# Performance wise, what's the optimal way to store lon and lat GEO data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-performance, scaling

In the process of teaching myself how to optimally design and build a database I've stumbled on the following question: what's the optimal way to store GEO-locations for addresses?

After doing some research I've found out there are two possibilities. Using either the MySQL `geometry` function and storing them as a `point(lon, lat)` in a single column.

Or storing them in 2 seperate columns as `lon float(10,6)` and `float(10,6)`.

However I've found little information on how many bytes a geometry function would use to store information.

Sample create table script

```
CREATE TABLE lonlatAsGeometry (
    ID INT,
    lonlat GEOMETRY
);

INSERT INTO lonlatAsGeometry VALUES (1, point(38.34886, -130.42156));
```

Sample #2

```
CREATE TABLE lonlatAsFloat (
    ID INT,
    lon FLOAT(10,6),
    lat FLOAT(10,6)
);

INSERT INTO lonlatAsFloat VALUES (1, 38.34886, -130.42156);
```

Comment: Yes, I think the spatial data types would be optimal.

Comment: Me too - use the spatial types and you will be able to compute path distances between them.

Comment: @Strawberry what reasons do you have to believe that?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Calculating distances between 2 geo locations will not be necessary

Comment: If you only want to store the locations but will not search through them or do any other computation (like distance) - then you may safely use 2 float columns.

Comment: So what *will* you do with this location information?

Comment: @IVOGELOV yes I chose for this solution aswell, see my answer for the reasoning.

Comment: @Strawberry using it to pinpoint addresses on a map using a 3rd party API :)

Comment: Define "optimal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that a `float` uses 4 bytes to store data,

whilst a `point` uses up to 25 bytes depending on the length of the values in it.

Source = https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html

Comment: 2*4 = 8 bytes for the combo of lat & lng.  Still that is significantly smaller than 25.

Answer (score 0):

Never use `FLOAT(m,n)`.  It happens to be OK for lat/lng, but it does unnecessary things to the numbers when inserting/fetching.

How much resolution do you need?

```
Representation       bytes  Resolution      Use
------------------   ----- ---------------  ------
DECIMAL(4,2)/(5,2)     5  1570 m    1.0 mi  Cities
SMALLINT scaled        4   682 m    0.4 mi  Cities
DECIMAL(6,4)/(7,4)     7    16 m     52 ft  Houses/Businesses
MEDIUMINT scaled       6   2.7 m    8.8 ft
FLOAT                  8   1.7 m    5.6 ft
DECIMAL(8,6)/(9,6)     9    16cm    1/2 ft  Friends in a mall
DOUBLE                16   3.5nm     ...    Fleas on a dog
```

-- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices

Back to your question... What do you mean by "optimal"?  Above are some choices for minimizing space used when storing separate lat/lng.  As already mentioned `POINT` takes 25 bytes.  If you have under, say, a million points, then space is probably not a big concern.  But maybe "optimal" relates to your *use* of the values.  If you are using `SPATIAL` features, then `POINT` is probably optimal.  Etc.

Bottom line:  7 bytes for "addresses on a map" if you use `DECIMAL(6,4)` for latitude (-90..90) and `DECIMAL(7,4)` for longitude (-180..180).